# jQuery handler to trigger upon window strict width and/or window resize if window width is less than a strict amount

Tags: jquery

Sorry for the elongated title, Im looking for your help in solving an issue that's driving me mad slowly.

I am trying to find a way in which I can run a function under certain circumstances. Those circumstances are the following:

- function will trigger if the window width is equal to or less than a specific value (496) upon page load
- function will run if the window is resized down to the above value or less than
- function wont run if window width is greater than above value on page load or window resize

If that has confused any of you I apologise, here is the code I have thus far to help explain it further.

jQuery:

```
if($(window).width() < 496 || ($(window).resize() && $(window).width() < 496)) {
    add_cta_arrows_for_mobile();
}

function add_cta_arrows_for_mobile() {
    $("#hori_ctas h4").addClass('arrow-down');

    $("#hori_ctas h4").click(function() {

        if($(this).attr('data-state') == 'dropped') {
            $(this).removeAttr('data-state').removeClass('arrow-up').addClass('arrow-down');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('data-state','dropped').removeClass('arrow-down').addClass('arrow-up');
        }
        $(this).next().children('div').slideToggle(800);
    });
}
```

I have not included the html or CSS as I don't feel there is a need, as this is just function over design.

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to help.

Comment: You want to check whenever resizing happens but the code as you wrote will be executed for once I guess .. `$(window).resize(function(){ //write code  })` should be the way. Help is here : http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I have looked into that and could not find a way, I need to find a way to combine all conditions into one, the if the function is called twice separately then it will run twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// cache relevant elements
var $win = $(window),
    $target = $("#hori_ctas"),
    $titles = $target.find('h4');

function add_cta_arrows_for_mobile() {
    // add arrow and event handler class, remove otherwise
    if($win.innerWidth() < 496) {
        $titles.addClass('clickable arrow-down');
    } else {
        $titles.removeClass('clickable arrow-down');
    }
}

// no need to bind event handler on every resize, do it once with delegation
$target.on('click', '.clickable', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        state = $this.data('state');

    // toggle class and state
    $this
        .data('state', state == 'dropped' ? '' : 'dropped')
        .toggleClass('arrow-up arrow-down')
        .next().children('div')
            .slideToggle(800);
});

$win.on('resize', function() {
    add_cta_arrows_for_mobile()
});

// initially set arrows
add_cta_arrows_for_mobile();
```

Note: to not always bind and unbind the event handler on window resize, just bind the function to a class with delegation and toggle this class.

Comment: Hi Simon thank you for helpig out, your solution stops the function from running more than once; as explained in Ishiaque's answer, as I had it previously but it still has the original problem of the <h4> element running the function when clicked if the browser window is greater than 496

Comment: Oh so it must be unbound, ok.

Comment: Ok I tried your update; had to change `if($win.innerWidth() < 496) {` to `if($win.width() < 496) {` as it was triggering at the wrong point but baring that this works as I hoped, thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
 function add_cta_arrows_for_mobile() {


                $("#hori_ctas h4").addClass('arrow-down');

                $("#hori_ctas h4").click(function() {

                    if($(this).attr('data-state') == 'dropped') {
                        $(this).removeAttr('data-state').removeClass('arrow-up').addClass('arrow-down');
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr('data-state','dropped').removeClass('arrow-down').addClass('arrow-up');
                    }
                    $(this).next().children('div').slideToggle(800);
                });
            }

        var $win = $(window);

        $win.load(function(){

        if($win.width() <= 496 ) {
               add_cta_arrows_for_mobile();
        }else{

         $("#hori_ctas h4").unbind('click'); 
        }

            });

            $win.resize(function(){



            if($win.width() <= 496 ) {
                add_cta_arrows_for_mobile();
            }else{


                $("#hori_ctas h4").unbind('click');


}


            });
```

**EDIT:**  Added the `if($win.width() <= 496 )` condition

**EDIT2:** `unbind`ed the click event if window width => 496

Comment: That wont work im afraid, one the initial add_cta_arrows_for_mobile(); function can only run when the browser window is <= 496px also this will cause the function to run twice upon click on certian circumstances. I have tried this approach already.

Comment: ' will cause the function to run twice upon click on certian circumstances'- which circumstances ?

Comment: if the browser loads at a width greater than '496' and then the window is resized to '496' or less than, clicks make the function run twice.

Comment: Does clicking resize the window to <= 496 px ?

Comment: No, by resizing i mean the user drags the edges of the browser to resize it. Additional, your most up to date code has insinuated the problem with the code running more than once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26532/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-daniel-wrigley)